# Specific time series dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have one year of 5 minute data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2019 00:05', 1], ['1/1/2019 00:10', 5],['1/1/2019 00:15', 1], ['1/1/2019 00:20',3], ['1/1/2019 00:25', 1],
                   ['1/1/2019 00:30', 2], ['1/1/2019 00:35', 6],['1/1/2019 00:40', 8],['1/1/2019 00:45', 1], ['1/1/2019 00:55', 2],
                   ['1/1/2019 01:00', 8],['1/1/2019 01:05', 1], ['1/1/2019 01:10', 5],['1/1/2019 01:15', 1], ['1/1/2019 01:20',3],['1/1/2019 01:25', 1],
                   ['1/1/2019 01:30', 2], ['1/1/2019 01:35', 6],['1/1/2019 01:40', 8],['1/1/2019 01:45', 1], ['1/1/2019 01:55', 2],
                   ['1/1/2019 02:00', 8]],
                  columns = ['Date','Value'])
```

And I'm looking to transpose it hourly for all the corresponding period. Now each row corresponds to one hour for a specific day and specific month. Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['day1hour0month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3],  ['day1hour1month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], 
                   ['day1hour2month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], ['day1hour3month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], 
                   ['day1hour4month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], ['day1hour5month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], 
                   ['day1hour6month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], ['day1hour7month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], 
                   ['day1hour8month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], ['day1hour9month1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3,3], 
                   ['day31hour23month12', 1, 1, 8, 0, 6, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2,3,5]],
                  columns = ['Date', 'min05', 'min10', 'min15', 'min20', 'min25', 
                             'min30', 'min35', 'min40', 'min45', 'min50',
                             'min55', 'min60'])
```

Is there any way to do it using Pandas time-series functionality (without using a for loop)? I would really appreciate any suggestion for implementing this operation.

Thank you in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample dataframe:

```
In [2213]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
In [2191]: df1['dmh'] = 'day' + df.Date.dt.day.astype(str) + 'hour' + df.Date.dt.hour.astype(str) + 'month' + df.Date.dt.month.astype(str)

In [2199]: df['minute'] = 'min' + df.Date.dt.minute.astype(str)

In [2211]: df.pivot(index='dmh', columns='minute', values='Value')                                                                                                                                          
Out[2211]: 
minute           min0  min10  min15  min20  min25  min30  min35  min40  min45  min5  min55
dmh                                                                                       
day1hour0month1   NaN    5.0    1.0    3.0    1.0    2.0    6.0    8.0    1.0   1.0    2.0
day1hour1month1   8.0    5.0    1.0    3.0    1.0    2.0    6.0    8.0    1.0   1.0    2.0
day1hour2month1   8.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
```